# File Path problem

Tags: path

I am relatively new to Unix, so perhaps this is an extremely simple problem.
Anyways, the problem is such:

I am taking an online course and the professor typed:

```
echo $path
```

and got this result....

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

I typed the same command (`echo $path`)

and I got:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

because this class is related to web development (we will be using gitHub and Node.js) ... will this slightly more complicated path become an issue?
Should I change the location of mysql?

Comment: Welcome to U&L. Are you sure you typed a space between `$` and `path` and that if you did not your return value did not start with a `/` (i.e. `/usr/local/...`.)  I formatted your code and removed non-relevant parts from your post. click on the `edited ...` link to see what changed. A better readable post, is more likely to be understood and answered.

Answer (score 7):

This is not a problem at all.

The $PATH variable simply states where executables reside in your filesystem.

When you want to run a program from your shell, normally you would have to type the complete path to this program to run - e.g. `/bin/grep`.
But since the path `/bin` is included in your $PATH variable, you only have to type `grep`. In other words, when you type a single command in your shell, the directories in your $PATH variable are searched for that command. If it is found there, it is executed without you having to find the location of the program and typing the whole path.

Comment: Thanks, geruetzel.  I thought it meant that all of the files below /usr/local had been moved to an SQL file system.  If so, I was worried that the functionality of most programs might be impeded.  Thanks for the tip...

Comment: You are welcome. If my post helped you, I would appreciate if you marked my question as accepted solution ;)